# Delphi XE project 'Run Parameters' setting will not persist between sessions

Tags: delphi, parameters, editor, debugging

I've noticed that after exiting Delphi XE and returning the Run | Parameters (command-line) settings are empty. They can be recalled using the drop-down list of course, but this is a pain and I would expect the previous session entries to persist. Am I missing a checkbox somewhere?
Thanks for any advice.

Steps:

1. Load XE
2. File, New, VCL Forms App.
3. Run, Parameters, enter something eg /test.
4. Save project.
5. Quit.
6. Restart XE, reload project. Run Parameters is empty.

I've tried setting 'save project desktop' etc

Comment: They always persist fine for me in D2010 and I'd be surprised if there was a regression on this in XE. They are part of the project settings. Are you saving the project before quitting?

Comment: Works like a charm here using XE.  Do you have specific steps?

Comment: Try to check your `*.dproj` file. It should contain under `Project / ProjectExtensions / BorlandProject / Delphi.Personality / Parameters` node the `RunParams` parameter with your settings.

Comment: @Bruce: 1. Load XE 2. File, New, VCL Forms App. 3. Run, PArameters, enter something eg /test. 4. Save project. 5.quit. 6.Restart XE, reload project. Run Parameters is empty. I've tried setting 'save project desktop' etc.

Comment: I am unable reproduce using steps provided and version 15.0.3953.35171 .   I recently thought I found a bug and an add-in/Expert was installed that ended causing the problem.   What Experts do you have installed?

Comment: @Robert: My version is the same as yours. Experts are: IDE Fix Pack XE 3.5, DDevExtensions 2.3, GExperts. Would these possibly be a cause?

Comment: @Brian it is very possible, disable all of them and restart the IDE.   Perform your test.  If it works then one of them is at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be simple in the end - I was using the excellent [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/) but with the option 'Local Start Parameters - dont store in dproj' checked. Doh!
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `Local Start Parameters` is intended to be used when the project is under version control ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all of the files in the project aren't read-only (at least for testing).  Your source-control system might be locking files that aren't checked-out...